# How to use photos filters in iOS 7

Tags: ios7, camera

Quick question here, I didn't find the answer around here or in apple docs. Is it possible to use the filters in camera mode like apple does in the camera application?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to Apply filters on photo, selected from Photogallery or captured from Camera then You can refer to this link [Apply Filter on Image](https://github.com/OmidH/Filtrr)

Answer (score 1):

Ok it seems it is not possible to use Apple's filters options. That what I wanted to know. I'll check alternatives. Thank you.

Comment: did you have any luck with this?